# The best way of parsing xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

What do you suggest to use for parsing such as this XML file:

```xml
<file>
  <test1 a="true">
    <line1>aaa</line1>
    <line2>aaa</line2>
    <line3>aaa</line3>
    <line4>aaa</line4>
  </test1>
  <test2 a="true">
    <line1>aaa</line1>
    <line2>aaa</line2>
    <line3>aaa</line3>
    <line4>aaa</line4>
  </test2>
  <test3 a="false">
    <line1>aaa</line1>
    <line2>aaa</line2>
    <line3>aaa</line3>
    <line4>aaa</line4>
  </test3>
</file>
```

- XmlReader
- XmlTextReader
- something another?

I'm looking for the fastest and shortest way. I tried with XmlReader but it needs to much extra variables to check which element is parasing currently.

Thanks in advance.
C.H.

--update 1--
The work which i want to do is assigning each element of tests to struct "test"

Comment: Before looking for *fastest* and *shortest* way, find a *way* that works.

Comment: What kind of parsing are you doing? (e.g. applying a template to each element or searching for the first node that meets a criteria)  What sort of work load are you expecting? (are you re-using the same document over and over, new xml each time, are you modifying the xml document, etc)

Comment: You've numbered all your tagnames. That's redundant and unusual in xml. Just name the fields with "test" or "line". If you parse it e.g. with xPath you have the position() function to get this information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in to [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). I can't speak to 'fastest', but it certainly makes my life easier when working with XML.

Comment: Agreed. This is definitely the easiest way.  [Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx) to the samples for parsing it, rather than creating a new document.

Answer (score 1):

If the file format is not changing frequently use deserialization. It will give you collection of object you are using to deserialize the file with. That's easiest way. You can read more serialization and deserialization. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073(v=vs.100).aspx

For the fastest, all of these depends on the size of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a concern then this is a very fast parser

http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php